# Does deleting a file from my computer also delete it from Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, delete

If I delete from my computer something, will that be deleted from my Ubuntu One cloud? If not, then how can I delete it? I'm new here and I'm confused how all this works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a file from your Ubuntu One folder,  [or any other folder that you selected](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/can-i-sync-folders-outside-the-ubuntu-one-folder/) to sync with Ubuntu One, it will be deleted from your Ubuntu One cloud as well.

The Ubuntu One Cloud will not show those files in the browser anymore, however, they may still be available on the server.

From [Ubuntu One help](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-can-i-recover-files-deleted-from-my-account/)

> When you delete a file from a desktop or mobile device, it might end
>   up in the Trash folder. It might also skip the Trash (depending on how
>   you deleted it), but when Ubuntu One syncs, it will move that file to
>   the other devices' Trash folder. So, for instance: if you want to
>   recover a file you deleted from your phone, you should be able to see
>   it in your computer's Trash folder.
>
> As of October 2013, you also have a way to recover them from the
>   server: In your Ubuntu One profile in the web, you can chose the
>   option "Recover deleted files". This will start a job that will
>   recover the deleted files and will place them in a folder called
>   "Recovered" followed by the date of the recovery.
>
> Each time you hit the "Recover deleted files" button, Ubuntu One will
>   try to recover all the files deleted since the last time you made a
>   recovery. The first time you try to recover, Ubuntu One will try to
>   recover all the files you deleted since the beginning of times.This
>   might take a while to sync in your devices, depending on how many
>   files are being recovered.
>
> The directory structure of the deleted files will be preserved under
>   the "Recovered" folder, so when you're looking for a specific file,
>   please take this to account to look in the right place.
>
> Please take to account that files deleted more than 60 days ago might
>   not be there. You can try to recover them anyway, but they might have
>   been deleted from the server too.

---

While I can tell you from personal experience that the restore files works, it is time consuming as you have to let the files restore to the restore folder then copy them back to the correct folder then delete the restore folder, but it is better than losing them completely.

(I did something wrong when syncing my VM and it erased all my synced files, the restore function was able to restore all my lost files, as well as some that were well over 60 days old. (the time must be relative as to how full your cloud is, mine is only 20% filled))